# ZF3: How to get view of an action from another action in the controller?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-view, zend-framework3

In my controller action, I want to grap a rendered full page of another action:

```
class MycontrollerController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function firstactionAction()
    {
         $html = some_function_to_get_the_rendered_page_of_secondaction();
    }

    public function secondactionAction()
    {
         return new ViewModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Be careful to use setTemplate()

**MycontrollerControllerFactory.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller\Service;

use Application\Controller\MycontrollerController;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class MycontrollerControllerFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $controller = new MycontrollerController();
        $controller->setRenderer($container->get('Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer'));
        return $controller;
    }
}
```

**MycontrollerController.php**

```
<?php

namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;

class MycontrollerController extends AbstractActionController
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer
     */
    protected $renderer;

    /**
     * @return \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer
     */
    public function getRenderer()
    {
        return $this->renderer;
    }

    /**
     * @param  \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer $renderer
     * @return self
     */
    public function setRenderer($renderer)
    {
        $this->renderer = $renderer;
        return $this;
    }

    public function firstAction()
    {
        if ($this->yourMethod()) {
            $secondView = $this->secondAction();
            $html = $this->getRenderer()->render($secondView);
        }

        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate('namespace/my-controller/first');
        return $view;
    }

    public function secondAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate('namespace/my-controller/second');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Comment: This was useful, but I still need more help. Let's say I did this `$otherViewModel = $this->secondAction();` , now I want to get the rendered html of that view model, something like `$html = $otherViewModel->some_render_function()`, how to do that?

Comment: I have modified my answer ;-)

Comment: OMG this is perfect! :D

Comment: Seems like the '$renderer->render($viewModel);' returns the HTML of the view WITHOUT the layout, which is what I'm looking for. But now I'm wondering if it's also possible to get the HTML WITH the layout..? If the answer is "yes it's possible", I'll ask it as a separate question

Comment: I have added a new answer.

Answer (score 1):

So, I suggest to create a new plugin 'htmlRender' :

module.config.php

```
'controller_plugins' => [
    'factories' => [
        'htmlRender' => Application\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Service\HtmlRenderFactory::class,
    ],
],
```

HtmlRenderFactory.php

```
<?php
namespace Application\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\Service;

use Application\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\HtmlRender;
use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;
use Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer;

class HtmlRenderFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $plugin = new HtmlRender();
        $plugin->setRenderer($container->get(PhpRenderer::class));
        return $plugin;
    }
}
```

HtmlRender.php

```
<?php
namespace Application\Mvc\Controller\Plugin;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\Plugin\AbstractPlugin;
use Zend\View\Renderer\RendererInterface;

class HtmlRender extends AbstractPlugin
{
    /**
     * @var \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer
     */
    protected $renderer;

    /**
     * @param  string|\Zend\View\Model\ModelInterface $nameOrModel
     * @param  null|array|\Traversable $values
     * @param  string|bool|\Zend\View\Model\ModelInterface $layout
     * @return string
     */
    public function __invoke($nameOrModel, $values = null, $layout = false)
    {
        $content = $this->getRenderer()->render($nameOrModel, $values);
        if (!$layout) {
            return $content;
        }

        if (true === $layout) {
            $layout = 'layout/layout';
        }
        return $this->getRenderer()->render($layout, [
            'content' => $content,
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * @return \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer
     */
    public function getRenderer()
    {
        return $this->renderer;
    }

    /**
     * @param  \Zend\View\Renderer\PhpRenderer|RendererInterface $renderer
     * @return self
     */
    public function setRenderer(RendererInterface $renderer)
    {
        $this->renderer = $renderer;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

Use in the MycontrollerController.php

```
<?php
class MycontrollerController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function firstAction()
    {
        if ($this->yourMethod()) {
            // Option 1 without layout
            $html = $this->htmlRender($secondView);
            // Option 2 without layout
            $html = $this->htmlRender('namespace/my-controller/second', $yourVariables));

            // Option 1 with layout
            $html = $this->htmlRender($secondView, null, true);
            //$html = $this->htmlRender($secondView, null, 'layout/my-custom-layout');
            // Option 2 with layout
            $html = $this->htmlRender('namespace/my-controller/second', $yourVariables, true));
            //$html = $this->htmlRender('namespace/my-controller/second', $yourVariables, 'layout/my-custom-layout');
        }

        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate('namespace/my-controller/first');
        return $view;
    }

    public function secondAction()
    {
        $view = new ViewModel();
        $view->setTemplate('namespace/my-controller/second');
        return $view;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, your answer actually contains several answers I've been wondering about! The use of the custom plugin could be a good idea, but in my case, all I wanted to know (which I just released) is how to use the phpRenderer. Thank you so much. I'll keep your first answer as the correct answer because it answers the original question